# how to perform performance testing of an application whose password is encrypted

Tags: jmeter

The website uses a password Encryption algorithm that comes from amazon such as, 1. Client send a request 2. Server Authenticate the request and send a random key 3. The random key is interpreted by client & it process it with password 4. Client send encrypted password to server 5. The sever Authenticate & if validate it set user cookies in browser 6. The cookie is validated in all request send to sever after login for validation .

I am unable to eradicate the errors and I am unable to proceed ahead with the performance testing of the application

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to determine the [encryption algorithm](https://www.toptenreviews.com/software/articles/encryption-algorithms/) and logic, it might be the case you will be able to use JMeter's built-in [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) to perform the password encryption.
2. If `__digest()` function doesn't support the algorithm required for encoding the password - you can still do this using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) or [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), check out [How to Handle Dynamic AWS SigV4 in JMeter for API Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-dynamic-aws-sigv4-in-jmeter-for-api-testing) for example approach/code
3. You can use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) in order to add a custom [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) to your request.